# Error using vertical: Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I am working on a multilayer perceptron classifier (on fisher iris data set, so multiclass classification) and I am getting the above mentioned(on the title of this question) error. I do not know why, since my matrices have same rows and columns. Everything seems to be correct, but obviously something's not!

CODE:

```
% Perceptron(Multilayer perceptron)

% coding (+1/-1) of 3 classes
a = [-1 -1 +1]';%'//
b = [-1 +1 -1]';%'//
c = [+1 -1 -1]';%'//
% define training inputs
rand_ind = randperm(50);
trainSeto = meas(rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainVers = meas(50 + rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainVirg = meas(100 + rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainInp = [trainSeto trainVers trainVirg];
% define targets
T = [repmat(a,1,length(trainSeto)) repmat(b,1,length(trainVers))
repmat(c,1,length(trainVirg))];
```

So, what is wrong with my code and how could I fix it?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What's `meas`? It's not a built-in function.

Comment: meas are the attributes (4 attributes) of the fisher iris data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meas=rand(200,4);
a = [-1 -1 +1]';%'//
b = [-1 +1 -1]';%'//
c = [+1 -1 -1]';%'//
% define training inputs
rand_ind = randperm(50);
trainSeto = meas(rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainVers = meas(50 + rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainVirg = meas(100 + rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainInp = [trainSeto trainVers trainVirg];
% define targets
tmp1 = repmat(a,1,length(trainSeto));
tmp2 = repmat(b,1,length(trainVers));
tmp3 = repmat(c,1,length(trainVirg));
T = [tmp1 tmp2 tmp3];
clear tmp1 tmp2 tmp3 %// Used for cleaning the temporaries
```

I think MATLAB has difficulties processing the three `repmat` calls within the concatenation operator (`[]`). i.e. I think it tries to `repmat` the first, but gets stuck on how and when to `repmat` the second. If you define temporary variables it works fine. You can use a `clear` call if you do not want the temporaries to clutter your workspace.

Comment: As I commented above replying to your comment the meas is a 150x4 matrix with the attributes of the fisher iris data set. So, meas = rand(200,5) is wrong. Meas is already given.

Comment: @Jimbo_ai Well of course, but I needed something to make the code working. The rest of the code works, the temporary variables part is the important bit...

Comment: Nevertheless, your answer was useful and solved this problem(despite I am coming up with a new one now..).

Comment: @Jimbo_ai if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I was lost into my code...would you like to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106678/error-function-subsindex-is-not-defined-for-values-of-class-network ?? My new problem and the last one , I hope!