# Error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'network'

Tags: matlab, perceptron

I am working on a multilayer perceptron classifier (on fisher iris data set, so multiclass classification) and I am getting the above mentioned(on the title of this question) error.

CODE:

```
% Perceptron(Multilayer perceptron)

% coding (+1/-1) of 3 classes
a = [-1 -1 +1]';   %'
b = [-1 +1 -1]';   %'
c = [+1 -1 -1]';   %'
% define training inputs
rand_ind = randperm(50);
trainSeto = meas(rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainVers = meas(50 + rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainVirg = meas(100 + rand_ind(1:35),:);
trainInp = [trainSeto trainVers trainVirg];
% define targets
tmp1 = repmat(a,1,length(trainSeto));
tmp2 = repmat(b,1,length(trainVers));
tmp3 = repmat(c,1,length(trainVirg));
T = [tmp1 tmp2 tmp3];
clear tmp1 tmp2 tmp3;
%% network training
trainCor = zeros(10,10);
valCor = zeros(10,10);
Xn = zeros(1,10);
Yn = zeros(1,10);
for k = 1:10
    Yn(1,k) = k;
    for n = 1:10
        Xn(1,n) = n;
        net = newff(trainInp,T,[k n],{},'trainbfg');
        net = init(net);
        net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1;
        net.divideParam.valRatio = 0;
        net.divideParam.testRatio = 0;
        %net.trainParam.show = NaN;
        net.trainParam.max_fail = 2;
        valSeto = 0;
        valVers = 1;
        valVirg = 2;
        valInp = [valSeto valVers valVirg];
        VV.P = valInp;
        tmp1 = repmat(a,1,length(valSeto));
        tmp2 = repmat(b,1,length(valVers));
        tmp3 = repmat(c,1,length(valVirg));
        valT = [tmp1 tmp2 tmp3];
        net = train(net,trainInp,T,[],[],VV);%,TV); //HERE IS THE ERROR!
        Y = sim(net,trainInp);
        [Yval,Pfval,Afval,Eval,perfval] = sim(net,valInp,[],[],valT);
        % calculate [%] of correct classifications
        trainCor(k,n) = 100 * length(find(T.*Y > 0)) / length(T);
        valCor(k,n) = 100 * length(find(valT.*Yval > 0)) / length(valT);
    end
end
clear tmp1 tmp2 tmp3;
figure;
surf(Xn,Yn,trainCor/3);
view(2);
figure;
surf(Xn,Yn,valCor/3);
view(2);
%% final training
k = 3;
n = 3;
fintrain = [trainInp valInp];
finT = [T valT];
net = newff(fintrain,finT,[k n],{},'trainbfg');
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 0;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 0;
net = train(net,fintrain,finT);
finY = sim(net,fintrain);
finCor = 100 * length(find(finT.*finY > 0)) / length(finT);
fprintf('Num of neurons in 1st layer  = %d\n',net.layers{1}.size);
fprintf('Num of neurons in 2nd layer  = %d\n',net.layers{2}.size);
fprintf('Correct class   = %.3f %%\n',finCor/3);
%% Testing
% define test set
testInp = [testSeto testVers testVirg];
tmp1 = repmat(a,1,length(testSeto));
tmp2 = repmat(b,1,length(testVers));
tmp3 = repmat(c,1,length(testVirg));
testT = [tmp1 tmp2 tmp3];
testOut = sim(net,testInp);
testCor = 100 * length(find(testT.*testOut > 0)) / length(testT);
fprintf('Correct class   = %.3f %%\n',testCor/3);
% plot targets and network response
clear tmp1 tmp2 tmp3;
figure;
plot(testT');   %'
xlim([1 21]);
ylim([0 2]);
set(gca,'ytick',[1 2 3]);
hold on;
grid on;
plot(testOut','r');   %'
legend('Targets','Network response');
xlabel('Sample No.');
```

So, why do I get this error and how could I fix it?

**EDIT**

The line the error occurs is the following:

```
net = train(net,trainInp,T,[],[],VV);%,TV);
```

Error message:

```
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'network'.

Error in first_exercise (line 260)
    net = train(net,trainInp,T,[],[],VV);%,TV);

Error in run (line 96)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Comment: Error is self-explanatory: You can't use the function `subsindex` for inputs of type `class`. Also: There's no such function in this code. Please share all errors you get or the code you actually do get this error with.

Comment: The train function exists (in 2015b release at least) and I know this part of code has worked in the past, but I do not have access in this project. For some reason, something is wrong and I do not know what and why..Nevertheless, I don't have any errors except this.

Comment: And I am talking about class 'network' specifically.

Comment: Still, we need to see where the error occurs, as there is no function `subsindex` in this code.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! Yes, I forgot to refer it...please check the edit!

Comment: Please include the complete error message

Comment: Check the edit, please. I just did it!

Comment: Indeed, I had in another part of my code a variable train. I checked it through my workspace and that was the reason!

Comment: @Adriaan the function `subsindex` is called automatically by MATLAB when an object is used as a subscript in an indexing expression - there's no need to call it explicitly.